# Grub window is not displayed

Tags: grub2

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 TS version in to my computer and burnt the ISO image in a DVD.
I followed the instructions of how to install ubuntu 12 as a dual boot in windows 7.

1) installed Ubuntu 12.04 in windows through CD

Note: During the ubuntu installation, there comes a window which asks to do partition of the space, it provides a mover. User can move left or right and automatically the space in bytes shows up
We dint do anything here. We left it untouched.   (have doubts whether this has created problems). We thought system will take it in a standard way.

2) it says installation is successful. We took out the CD

3) when we restart, I am not getting the window to select the OS(First problem)

4) after some time, it takes me to UBUNTU screen

5) in the username/ password window, most of the times, system hangs and i will get a drum sound(second problem)

6) very few times, i get a chance to type my username and password and i will be taken to Ubuntu

7) but, where is windows OS? How can I get back to Windows?

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: i think you replaced windows completely. which option did u choose at the time of installlation? alongside of windows or anything else?

Comment: I selected "Install Ubuntu along with windows" option

Answer (score 0):

Try Boot repair by a ubuntu live cd.

Procedures:

1. Insert the disk and select try ubuntu
2. Then press **CTRL+ALT+T** to open terminal.
3. Then copy+paste this command  `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
4. Press **Enter**.
5. Then again copy+paste this command `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`.
6. remove the disk and reboot your system.

`

Comment: Thanks a lot. while doing the above, do I need to connect the internet to my PC?

Comment: yes. You have to connect your PC with internet.